# Switch the first two commits in a git history

Tags: git

I have a problem with the following repository. The initial commits were done in the wrong order - the older state was commited on top of the newer state instead of the other way round.

*How it is*

```
Commit    Branch name
3         <bugfix>
|
2         <1.6>
|
1         <master>
```

*How it should be*

```
Commit       Branch name
  3          <bugfix>
1 |          <master>
 \|
  2          <1.6>
```

Is there any way I can switch this around, so the history is correct without doing it all over?

Comment: If  you haven't pushed this state already you can use 'git rebase -i' to interactlvly rebase your commits and reorder them.If you already pushed this state, you don't have any chances to change the state unless you want to rewrite the whole history.

Comment: Rewriting the whole history would be acceptable, it's not used by many people yet and we can tell them to ditch their local repositories and get the new one. I'm asking how to exactly to the rebase, because the tutorial I found assumes there is a common parent to the branches, which I don't have.

Comment: Ok, then you can use git rebase -i also. Do the reordering and force-push the repo.

Comment: So `1.6` should be a merge commit of `master` and `bugfix`? In this case, I'm not sure `rebase -i` is enough...

Comment: 1.6 should be the first commit in the repository. master should have 1.6 as parent, and bugfix has 1.6 as parent as well (this is unchanged from before)

Comment: So `1.6`, `master` and `bugfix` are all more than 1 commit each?

Comment: @Moberg No, they are all a single commit, with a branch name referring to it.

Comment: Technically, `master` and `bugfix` would be *two* commits each: they both contain the very first commit, which is also contained in branch `1.6`.  That is, the first commit is on *all three* branches. Note that once you've restructured the repository, all three commits will have new, different hash IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dunno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41546518/1256452) can get you there, but isn't a simple "do these commands" recipe.  The big problem is moving a commit to a new root.

You have three commits (which you've numbered, 1 2 3; I usually prefer letters, A B C, and given the branch name `1.6` I think the letters will be much less confusing):

```
A   <-- master
 \
  B   <-- 1.6
   \
    C   <-- bugfix
```

Here I've drawn the older commits on the left and the newer ones on the right, rather than squeezing them in vertically the way `git log --all --decorate --online --graph` does.

The thing about commits—or indeed all Git objects, really—is that they are read-only: they can never be changed.  What we can and must do instead is to *copy* them to "similar but not the same" commits.  We want `B`, not `A`, to be the first (root) commit, and then `A` and `C` to use `B` as their parent commit.

We usually do this sort of thing with `git rebase`, and can do it with `git rebase --root`.  It's extra-tricky with rebase, though, because rebase "likes to" compute the *difference* between a commit and its parent.  With a root commit, the difference is that all the files get added—so no matter how we retrieve commit `A` using rebase, we're likely to get some conflicts.

Assuming you have the correct *source tree* attached to each commit, though, there's an easyish way to construct the desired commit sequence, after which we can simply move the three branch names to point to them.  This involves using the `git commit-tree` "plumbing" command, and some shell scripting to keep the new IDs.

First, we want to copy the tree (and, presumably, message) of commit `B` to a new commit with no parents:

```
newroot=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%B 1.6 | git commit-tree -F - 1.6^{tree})
echo $newroot
```

(The `-1 --pretty=format:%B` prints the entire log message for the one commit, and the `-F -` reads it back, to preserve it.  Depending on your shell, you *may* need to quote some of these characters, such as `^` and/or `{...}`: `git commit-tree -F - "1.6^{tree}"` for instance.)

This should print out the new root's hash ID (a big ugly 40-character-long thing identifying the new commit).  Now let's create a branch name pointing to this commit:

```
git branch new-1.6 $newroot
```

Next, we want to copy commit `A` (currently pointed-to by `master`) to a new commit, but set the new commit's parent to the new root.  We'll combine this with the creation of a new branch name:

```
git branch new-master $(git log -1 --pretty=format:%B master | git commit-tree -F - -p $newroot master^{tree})
```

Last, we want to copy commit `C` (currently pointed-to by `bugfix`) to a new commit, setting the new commit's parent to the new root again.  Once again we can combine this with the creation of a new branch name:

```
git branch new-bugfix $(git log -1 --pretty=format:%B bugfix | git commit-tree -F - -p $newroot bugfix^{tree})
```

We should now have this:

```
A   <-- master
 \
  B   <-- 1.6
   \
    C   <-- bugfix

  A'  <-- new-master
 /
B'   <-- new-1.6
 \
  C'  <-- new-bugfix
```

We can view these three new commits to make sure it all worked as desired:

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph --branches='new-*'
```

(using `--branches=...` lets us select just the new branches: rather than using "**a dog**", --**a**ll --**d**ecorate --**o**neline --**g**raph, we use the dog without `--all`).

If all looks good, we now simply force the existing branch names to point to the new commits, then delete the now-unnecessary new branch names:

```
git checkout new-1.6; git branch -f 1.6 new-1.6; git checkout 1.6
```

(this little dance is to make sure we're not moving the branch we're standing on)

```
git branch -f master new-master
git branch -f bugfix new-bugfix
git branch -D new-1.6
git branch -D new-master
git branch -D new-bugfix
```

This does assume that the *trees* (the work-tree associated with each original commit) really are the ones you want for each commit.  If not, you don't want to use this recipe.

Comment: This actually helped quite much. I tried it out in a simple repo and it seems to work. The only "ugly" parts are that it seems the commit messages are lost. But I guess that can be worked around with a rebase/amend after everything was done, right?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka: Ah, the `git log | ...` were supposed to preserve the log messages, but there are two mistakes here: we need `-1` to show just one log message, and we need to add `-F -` to the `git commit-tree` commands to make them *read* the log messages. Will fix the above.

Comment: With the fixes it works like charm! Awesome script, thanks :-) The fact that the new history is squashed (if there are more commits in a branch) is not pretty but still, better like this than a completely wrong ordered history! :-)

Comment: You can retain more commits, but if you have a lot of commits that you want to take mostly in order, a rebase sequence (which replays them as patches rather than just picking them up whole-cloth like this) will be easier.

Comment: But didn't you say that it's not doable with rebase because I need a new root? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Setting up the new root is bit of a pain with rebase (though using `--root` helps a lot).  Once you have the root itself in place, though, you can replay the *rest* of the commits onto the new root-setup.

Comment: Ah, sure. Okay. I'll play around a bit. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

This is a more complicated scenario, and rebase -i isn't enough. You'll want to do two things - delete `1` from before `1.6` and put it again on master, after `1.6`.

First thing can be done by `rebase -i` and deleting the line with the commit you want to delete. Before you do that, however, make a temporary branch or your commit will be lost.

```
git checkout 1
git branch tmp # this is just for safety
git checkout 1.6
git rebase -i <sha_of_commit_before_1>
```

Now that you deleted commit `1` You can place it again on top of 1.6 by doing

```
git checkout master
git merge 1.6
git cherry-pick <sha_of_commit_1>
```

Comment: There is no "commit before 1". It's the first commit of the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Chechkout `1.6` and remove the commits not wanted (`master´) with

```
git rebase --interactive --root
```

Rebase the `master` and `bugfix` branches with:

```
git rebase -i 1.6
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the result will still be linear.

Comment: @torek: Correct, fixed.